# How to overcome shrink , in deseq?

Tags: r, coefficients

Currently trying differential expression between two groups. This code was working 6 months ago, but now I get :
*deseq2 library*

```
> converting counts to integer mode estimating size factors estimating
> dispersions gene-wise dispersion estimates mean-dispersion
> relationship final dispersion estimates fitting model and testing
> -- replacing outliers and refitting for 7129 genes
> -- DESeq argument 'minReplicatesForReplace' = 7 
> -- original counts are preserved in counts(dds) estimating dispersions fitting model and testing
> **Error in lfcShrink(dds = this.dds, contrast = c("condition", G1.desc,  :    type='apeglm' shrinkage only for use with 'coef' In
> addition: Warning message: In DESeqDataSet(se, design = design,
> ignoreRank) :   some variables in design formula are characters,
> converting to factors**



 this.dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = this.dat,
                                         colData = this.coldata,
                                         design = ~ condition)
      
      this.dds$condition <- factor(this.dds$condition, levels = c(G1.desc,G2.desc))
      
      if (! exists("Dseq_results")) {
        Dseq_results <- DESeq(this.dds)
      }
      this.dds <- Dseq_results
      res <- results(this.dds, 
                     name=sprintf("condition_%s_vs_%s",G1.desc,G2.desc),contrast = c('condition',G1.desc,G2.desc)
      )
      
      tmp1 <<- this.dds
      print(tmp1)
      res1 <- lfcShrink(dds=this.dds,contrast = c('condition',G1.desc,G2.desc), res=res)
  
  
  res1.nice=cbind(rownames(HTseq.counts),res1$baseMean,res1$log2FoldChange,res1$lfcSE,res1$stat,res1$pvalue,res1$padj)
  colnames(res1.nice)<-c('Gene','baseMean','log2FoldChange','lfcSE','stat','pvalue','padj')
  
  return(res1.nice)
```

g1,g2 are the groups, desc - description, this.dds - holds the data of htseq counts.
I tried changing the type in type from "apeglm" to 'ashr' but I got a different error. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but check you have apeglm installed (`BiocManager::install("apeglm")`)

Comment: Also, what do you get if you switch `contrast = c('condition',G1.desc,G2.desc)` for `coef = 2`? Or `coef = 1:2`?

Comment: apeglm already installed, if I switch coef, same error

Comment: first of all.. can you be precise about what happened. did the code not work once you upgraded your packages or it worked on another dataset and not on this?

Comment: secondly.. are you sure this ```this.dds$condition <- factor(this.dds$condition, levels = c(G1.desc,G2.desc))``` works?

Comment: I might upgraded by accident (tbh I don't remember that) but the code worked fluently some months ago on the same data but different samples (conditions), which easily changes. I can run deseq but without lfcshrink part, so I guess it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an example, i am really not sure about what you have for `G1.desc`, but lets say:

```
G1.desc = "A"
G2.desc = "B"

this.dat = matrix(rnbinom(3000,mu=50,size=0.1),ncol=6)
colnames(this.dat) = paste0("s",1:6)
this.coldata = data.frame(condition = rep(c("A","B"),each=3))
```

Factor before you put it into the deseq object, and here already you can decide the contrast:

```
this.coldata$condition = factor(this.coldata$condition,
levels=c(G1.desc,G2.desc))
```

Run DESeq:

```
this.dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = this.dat,
                                   colData = this.coldata,
                                   design = ~ condition)
      
this.dds <- DESeq(this.dds)
res <- results(this.dds, 
name=sprintf("condition_%s_vs_%s",G1.desc,G2.desc),
contrast = c('condition',G1.desc,G2.desc)
      )
```

And yes I get the same error as you on "apeglm":

```
l2fc = sapply(c("normal","ashr","apeglm"),function(i){
lfcShrink(dds=this.dds,
contrast = c('condition',G1.desc,G2.desc), res=res,type=i)$log2FoldChange
})

Error in lfcShrink(dds = this.dds, contrast = c("condition", G1.desc,  : 
  type='apeglm' shrinkage only for use with 'coef'
```

If you set the factors as I did above, the contrast is always going to be G2.desc vs G1.desc, you can see:

```
resultsNames(this.dds)
[1] "Intercept"        "condition_B_vs_A"
```

So you simply don't provide the `res =`  argument:

```
 l2fc = sapply(c("normal","ashr","apeglm"),function(i){
    lfcShrink(dds=this.dds,coef=2,type=i)$log2FoldChange
    })

head(l2fc)
         normal       ashr      apeglm
[1,] -0.2313623 -0.1739082 -0.02573008
[2,] -1.0543602 -0.8159166 -0.11381314
[3,]  2.2493688  1.8142392  0.24608219
[4,]  3.5059792  3.0354023  0.22795819
[5,]  2.8617158  2.3939858  0.32407906
[6,] -0.2236092 -0.1710536 -0.02053698
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. After removing the $ part, the lfcshrink does work but I get another error with "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" , which I am still not sure why because everything worked fluently (except shrink)

Comment: just do ```lfcShrink(dds=this.dds,coef=2,type="ape.glm"``` this works right? the rest of your error comes from cbind and i cannot troubleshoot it without having the data.